# Asp.net Post json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

**login.aspx.cs**

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string jQueryPageMethod(string name)
        {
            return "<h3>jQuery - PageMethod </h3>result" + name;
        }
```

**JS/Jquery:**

If i run below method it works.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'login.aspx/jQueryPageMethod',
    data: '{ "name":"exampleValue" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

If i run below method **it does not work**.

```
var somevalue = "Value";

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'login.aspx/jQueryPageMethod',
  data: '{ "name":' + somevalue + ' }', // Problem here
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

Where i miss in **second example in part of data** ?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you please provide the `error(s)` that you are getting?

Comment: i want to post value to jQueryPageMethod named method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `data: '{"queryname":"' + queryname + '"}'`

Comment: This is very strange. Somehow you are both doing something to the data before posting it with the http request. You mentioned json stringify - which will convert a string into a json object, but that is like crossing the river (twice) to get to the water...

Comment: I'm not jsonstringfying anything. Just passing the text variable given.

Answer (score 1):

Your data should not be formatted as a string, but rather as a javascript object like this:

```
data: { "name": somevalue }, // No Problem here :)
```

Comment: still same problem . Problem might occur because of string jsonstringfiy ?

Comment: @Soner I don't think you need that. Where do you use that - i see no use in your example? It looks very straightforward. My code should work unless there is more going on than what you posted?